# Yii2 Active Query как собрать запрос mysql с подзапросом?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Как через query builder собрать вот такой mysql запрос?

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tsg_message t1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT chat_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at FROM tsg_message GROUP BY chat_id
) t2
ON t1.chat_id = t2.chat_id AND t1.created_at = t2.max_created_at
```

Если это важно, то данный запрос мне нужен в SearchModel для группировки сообщений по признаку chat_id и мне нужно, чтобы в группировку попадали только самые последние сообщения. Есть у кого-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а почему обязательно делать на ActiveQuery? Ведь ни что не мешает так же использовать DAO. Это не противозаконно)) А если так сильно нужно, то я бы рекомендовал всё же открыть доки по AR и посмотреть, что принимают на вход каждые из элементов `select`/`join` и пр. И просто **поэтапно** строить, разбив запрос на простые части (в том числе на подзапрос). Как пример можно подсмотреть в https://stackoverflow.com/a/41289007/6138795 и https://stackoverflow.com/a/46673154/6138795

Comment: @СергейМишин большое спасибо за подсказку! Ниже размещу ответ на свой же вопрос. Все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Решение данного вопроса:

```
 $subQuery = Message::find()
            ->select(['chat_id', 'MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at'])
            ->groupBy('chat_id');
        $query = Message::find();
        $query->alias('t1');
        $query->innerJoin(['t2' => $subQuery], 't1.chat_id = t2.chat_id AND t1.created_at = t2.max_created_at');
```